# System.IO.FileNotFoundException: 'Could not load file or assembly 'System.Data.SqlClient, Version=4.4.0.0

Tags: c#, visual-studio, dll, .net-core

it is my first question here, I have been trying to find out my issue but I have not succeeded, so apologies if I am duplicating this question.

I am using Visual Studio v15.1.7 with .NET framework v4.6.01055.
I am trying to use one DLL generated from one file called Class1.cs which contains one method to connect to one DB and read its content as follows:

```
////////////////////////////////////////
using System;
using System.Data;
using System.Data.SqlClient;


namespace Milibreria
{
    public class Utilidades
    {
        public static DataSet Ejecutar(String cmd)
        {

                //set connection 
                System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = Administracion; Integrated Security = True");
                Con.Open();

                //Execute command and save results in DataSet
                DataSet DS = new DataSet();
                SqlDataAdapter DP = new SqlDataAdapter(cmd, Con);
                DP.Fill(DS);

                Con.Close();

                return DS;

        }
    }
}

/////////////////////////////////////////////////////
```

When I call Utilidades.Ejecutar(CMDd);
from my Form1.cs, error described in subject appears. How to solve?

Notes:

1.- In Form1, it has been added 'using Milibreria;'

2.- System.Data.SqlClient NuGet package has been added to Milibreria/Dependencies

3.- If I do not use DLL and I code this functionality directly inside one button Click event in Form1, it works perfectly.

4.- Issue appears exactly when I write into my DLL:
System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection Con = new System.Data.SqlClient.SqlConnection("Data Source =.; Initial Catalog = Administracion; Integrated Security = True");

Comment: Can you check property of System.Data.SqlClient.dll and version in the property window. Also confirm that file exists at the mentioned path.

Comment: what is target .net framework of your dll ?

Comment: You need to add `System.Data.SqlClient` dependency to the project where your `Form1` exist too.